# What does rdfs:domain and rdfs:range mean?

Tags: owl, ontology, semantic-web, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I simply do not understand what either `rdfs:domain` and `rdfs:range` mean.

I have read what is says [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/), but it isn't clear enough.

If someone could explain it with an example, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an object property `related` with domain `Class1` and range `Class2`, it will infer that whenever 2 individuals `x`,`y` are related via `related`, then `x` will be inferred to be of type `Class1` and `y` will be inferred to be of type `Class2`.

```
DomainRangeExample:related rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                           rdfs:domain DomainRangeExample:Class1 ;
                           rdfs:range DomainRangeExample:Class2 .

DomainRangeExample:Class1 rdf:type owl:Class .

DomainRangeExample:Class2 rdf:type owl:Class .

DomainRangeExample:x rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
                               DomainRangeExample:related DomainRangeExample:y .

DomainRangeExample:y rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
```

Comment: Most importantly, you should point out that rdfs:domain/range predicates are NOT constraints and users shall learn SHACL if that's what they are looking for.